# How I get value from JSON React Native?

Tags: json, react-native

This is my JSON response. Can you please tell me how can I get daily array values?
When I print `console.log(data.timezone)`, It is working but how can I print **daily[0].temp[0].day**

```
{
  "lat": 7.3127,
  "lon": 80.6831,
  "timezone": "Asia/Colombo",
  "daily": [
    {
      "dt": 1639290600,
      "sunrise": 1639269596,
      "temp": {
        "day": 28.45,
        "min": 19.96,
        "max": 28.6,
      }
    },
    {
      "dt": 1639290600,
      "sunrise": 1639269596,
      "temp": {
        "day": 28.45,
        "min": 19.96,
        "max": 28.6,
      }
    }
    {
      "dt": 1639290600,
      "sunrise": 1639269596,
      "temp": {
        "day": 28.45,
        "min": 19.96,
        "max": 28.6,
      }
    }
    
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

temp is not array ! is Object so you cant get index

```
console.log(data.daily[0].temp.day)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
daily = data.daily
for(let i=0; i < daily.length; i++){
console.log(daily[i].temp.day)
}
```